# How do I get the names of months and years from a DateTime list into a map?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the names of months and years from a DateTime list into a map?

For example: i have list of DateTime:
[22.01.2022, 24.01.2022, 15.02.2022, 29.03.2023]

I have to get on the way out:

```
{
 "jan22" = "January 2022",
 "feb22" = "February 2022"
 "mar23" = "March 2023"
}
```

Comment: ``list[index].month`` will return the month and ``.year`` will return year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your List is:

```
List<DateTime> dates = [
    DateTime(2022, 07, 01),
    DateTime(2022, 08, 04),
  ];
```

With [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, you can do this:

```
Map<String, String> result = {};
dates.forEach((date) {
      var shortMonth = DateFormat("MMM").format(date);
      var year = DateFormat("yy").format(date);
      var month = DateFormat("MMMM").format(date);
      result['$shortMonth$year'] = '$month ${date.year}';
    });


print("result= $result"); //result= {Jul22: July 2022, Aug22: August 2022}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse all the items in the list, and check for each of them that your map doesn't already have that value. I don't know if there is any function that can help you (i.e. maybe using `Set` instead of `Map`), but this should not be hard to achieve. Something like (it's almost pseudocode, don't expect to copy&paste and have no errors):

```
var map = <String, String>{};
var list = <DateTime>[/*your list*/];

for (var date in list){
   var key = "${date.month}${date.year}"; //adjust the key as you see fit
   if (!map.keys.contains(key)){
     map[key] = "${date.month}${date.year}"; //adjust the value stored as you see fit
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the list like this.**

```
 List<DateTime> dates = [
    DateTime.parse("2021-12-11"),
    DateTime.parse("2020-02-12"),
    DateTime.parse("2010-01-23"),
  ];
  Map<String,String> data = {};
```

**Here is how you can convert the list items in the needed format and add them to the Map.**

```
  dates.forEach((element) {
      String key = DateFormat('MMMdd').format(element).toLowerCase();
      String value = DateFormat('MMMM yyyy').format(element);
      data[key] = value;
    });
    print(data);
```

**Output:**

[image]